# How can I remove per user based session in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a MVC application with part of it having chat functionality using SignalR.

If the user user closes the browser we can get that user details through signalR **OnDisconnected** event. Then I need to remove that user associated session details from application. I'm using default session management.

Comment: What about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.clear(v=vs.110).aspx?

Comment: If you have the users info in the OnDisconnected event, then why not use that to remove the user from the application? How are you using their information for the chat?

Comment: @pwas,
Abandon or Clear method can remove the HttpContext.Current only. The SignalR OnDisconnected event is application based like global events from that I need to clear specific user session from the list of user session.

Comment: Let me explain the scenario,

Assume there are three users currently accessing our application let say A, B and C. And they are having  individual session that maintained by asp.net session management.

If A sign out the application then  asp.net session management can remove A's session. 

If B close the browser window I need to remove B's session immediately instead of waiting for the application's Session_End event.